# CLI to load html in phantomjs or chromium headless and get any javascript errors

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, command-line-interface, google-chrome-headless

I have a self-contained non-interactive html artifact that I would like to check for javascript errors in an automated single CLI call way so it can integrate with my java based functional tests. I just want to send the html file to some headless browser and get any errors like would be in the F12 console. Preferably this does not involve a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS has [page.onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) callback just for this purpose. Just conjure up a script that collects errors and have it write errors to a log or send via email, then run the script from cli when needed.